# How is a nonce RESTful when using HMAC?

Tags: rest, authentication, hmac, nonce

I'm trying to wrap my head around RESTful practices as I attempt to implement my own REST API, and that said, there's a fair bit that's confusing me.

One of the resources I've come across is the [REST Cookbook for logging in](http://restcookbook.com/Basics/loggingin/), and while I understand how a nonce works for HMAC authentication, I'm hung up on one of the caveats listed towards the bottom of the page:

> Using nonces can improve your security, but you MUST store and compare nonces server-side.

Now, the [original dissertation on the REST architecture](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) asserts the following about statelessness:

> #### 5.1.3 Stateless
>
> We next add a constraint to the client-server interaction: communication must be stateless in nature, as in the client-stateless-server (CSS) style of [Section 3.4.3](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/net_arch_styles.htm#sec_3_4_3) ([Figure 5-3](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#fig_5_3)), such that each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client.

This constraint has popularly disallowed old DHTML webapp methods of maintaining authentication (e.g. a cookie containing a "session ID" hash that identifies a user's subsequent requests). If a server needs to remember which nonce values have been used, isn't that technically maintaining state much like a session ID? If a legitimate client loses state, how can it generate a valid nonce when the server shouldn't be storing, let alone disclosing, stateful information?

I get a feeling I'm seeing something wrong, missing a piece of the puzzle, or misinterpreting something in this method, but I can't figure out what for the life of me...

Comment: The REST API requests and the authentication scheme are two independent layers of the same request, such TLS and how the TLS handshake isn't considered by the REST API.  Therefore, the REST nature of an API doesn't change if you add or replace the authentication scheme.  Thus, whether a lower layer is statefull or not doesn't change the architecture style followed while implementing an API.